# Tailcall elimination in Mono

Tags: .net, mono

I have a .NET 4.0 application that makes heavy use of tail recursion (programmed in F#). It runs fine on the .NET VM, but it runs out of stack on Mono-3.0.1.

I've tried running with `mono --optimize=tailc` but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there some way to force mono to eliminate tail calls?
Is there some way to increase the maximum stack size in mono?

Comment: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476785 -- [This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Runtime_Projects) says it's being worked on, but no projected completion date.

Comment: [This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Project_Roadmap) says that Tail Calls in F# were fixed in Version 2.12

Comment: 2.12 was renamed to 3.0; and anyway it says "optimizations", not "all optimizations", so I guess the one that Nikhil is hitting is not fixed yet

Comment: Thanks for these responses. Any ideas about my second question: I.e., how can I increase the max stack size in mono?

Comment: To change the stack size, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19909421/1822514) for one way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very similar more recent question with helpful answers: [Stack size under Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19817790/2157640)

As Robert Harvey already pointed out in the comments, Mono has broken/incomplete tail call support for F# ([bug 476785: Tail call support in F#](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476785)). Fix for this problem is [on Mono's runtime ongoing projects list](http://www.mono-project.com/Runtime_Projects#Runtime_Fixes).

Stack size can be increased either using `System.Threading.Thread` constructor or in the PE header. The `System.Threading.Thread` way [does not work in Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909421/2157640), though. For changing the PE, you'll probably [need MS Visual Studio](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a5e235b-5042-4b96-959c-497e865b73ba/how-to-increase-stack-size-of-a-net-exe-in-windows?forum=netfxbcl), since there may be no alternative to its [`editbin.exe /stack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35yc2tc3.aspx).